# In the Wagtail admin, is there an equivalent to the Django admin's save_model method?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a model whose instances I would like to restrict to a particular Wagtail `Site`, and so I want to automatically save the site with the model.  I've defined a `TenantAwareModel` from which I inherit when defining site-specific models:

```
class TenantAwareModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Wagtail provides the `site` as part of the `request`, so in the `wagtail_hooks.py` file I wanted to override `save_model` in the same way as can be done in the regular Django admin.  However, I've just discovered that there is no `save_model` method on Wagtail's `ModelAdmin`.  Is there a way to intercept a save in the Wagtail admin in order to insert a value that is taken from the request object (in this case the site) into the model?  I don't think I can use a `pre_save` signal because the `request` is not available in `pre_save()`.

Comment: I was just googling around with the same question and found this. Have you gotten anywhere with this ?

Comment: No, and I suspect there is no solution short of changing Wagtail code to match the Django admin code.  My site is for a local borough with an associated site for their police department.  The model that I want to associate with particular sites is a NewsItem model.  Since I have just two sites, I'm just going to create NewsItem as an abstract model and then create specifically named models (BoroNewsItem and PoliceNewsItem) and assign rights in the admin to users responsible for each site.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for an answer to this and arrived at this post. I was trying to intercept the save method on an email generation django app, but have also found that this just doesn't work.

It seems that in the wagtail ModelAdmin implementation, all we have is simple form validation and saving of data...

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/c72a4e09413bc6fc3a9cac8ed173378aa8652925/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py#L167

Here are all of the options in the class...

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/c72a4e09413bc6fc3a9cac8ed173378aa8652925/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py#L62

This suggests that it's possible to write your own views for create and edit, but that sort of negates the "simple registration of django models" notion if you have to rewrite and put all of your business logic into custom views to get anything other than basic CRUD functionality.